# How can i add signature to outlook.com/hotmail/office365 account?

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, hotmail, outlook.com

I want to know how can i apply a signature to my hotmail/outlook.com/office365 using REST API. I searched in google and stackoverflow for examples but didn't found any.

I checked the office365 REST API but they don't explain about USER OPTIONS/SETTINGS changes. I want to apply a signature to users account with my web interface.

Anybody help me on this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change your Email signature in O365 ? AFAIK, REST API doesn't support that . You could try to use EWS Managed API to add an email signature to an email for use with Exchange server, it includes Exchange Online as part of Office 365.Please click [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-Add-da090bce) for details and demo.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply. It really works for office365 but what about outlook.com/hotmail . How can i apply the signature to them?